# Use of "that" After A Verb

Tags: grammar

Consider the two sentences

> He reported that the car was on fire.
>
> He reported the car was on fire.

Which usage is considered correct?

Are there any hard and fast rule when to use or not use "that"?

Is there terminology that describes this usage/situation?

Answer (score 1):

In such sentences, *that* is often omitted in conversation, but a verb like *reported* is more likely to occur in writing, where it’s normal to retain *that*.